# Autoshow hidden divs on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pretty heavy (vertically-long) web page with lots of images. I want the top part of it to appear as fast as possible.

So I thought to only display the divs that are close to the top, and set the style/class for the divs well below the fold to "display:none;", thus preventing the browser from trying to load all the images and whatnot that they may contain until they are shown via "display:block;" when the user starts to scroll down.

Thus I have several questions:

1. Is my assumption correct that most modern browsers will not attempt to load images (or will load them last) if they are inside of a hidden div, and thus it will improve loading times?
2. How do I actually implement it via jQuery? I would imagine I will need some listener function for onscroll, but then how do I display on relevant divs, and not those to which the user has not yet scrolled? That is, as the user scrolls down, the divs get shown in order.
3. How to deal with #anchors pointing to hidden divs. What if I set them to `h` tags that will remain visible, will the onscroll function handle this case when the user clicks on a link pointing to such anchor?

Just for clarity: AJAX-based solution with calls to the server for more content are not viable.

Thank you.

Comment: Wrong, toggling display won't help faster page load.

Comment: if you want to increase page load time you would need to load the page as you scroll down, not just hide the content.  Have a google for load content on scroll, there are plenty of plugins out there

Comment: @Pete Actually I want to reduce page load times, not increase it. I want to reduce it by deferring loading of images mostly.

Comment: I meant to say reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer all three questions quickly:

1. a.f.a.i.k images in hidden divs are loaded anyways – so that won't probably help you improving your loading time
2. there is a jQuery Plugin for this exact use case which is rather easy to implement and quite well documented: [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)
3. I don't know about anchors pointing to hidden divs – i suppose that won't work. But with Lazy Load you won't have to actually *hide* the divs – instead the images would only be loaded when inside the view port (or close)

Comment: Thank you. Lazyload sounds interesting, but it has a weird requirement of setting image dimensions in advance. That could prove to be highly problematic.

Comment: if i remember correctly that is needed to determine whether a div is 'near' the fold – but I agree it can therefore be a bit complicated to handle

Comment: It actually works well, except images, when loaded are displayed 100% scale, and thus overflow my layout. Any tip on how to fix this?

Comment: I think you can tame the pics by placing them in div-containers – or did you already get the 100%-issue fixed?

Comment: I fixed it using max-width property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. YOU will have to do that by preloading the images. This is a hover example: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/image-preloader/ , what you need is probably `onScroll` preloader. Google it!
2. An example: http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/ , there's more out there.

Comment: Thank you for the info. However not sure how preloader would help, when in fact I want to defer loading and load only on demand (i.e. when image is in view). I will research the script you provided, however it has some issues: namely requirement of data-src attribute instead of src, not very friendly for SEO as far as I know.

Comment: You don't have to use that script. That was an example. I'm sure there are other out there that are SEO friendly. This is what you're looking for, preloading the images once the user reaches that section of the website.